# Representing a hyperbola in Java, and their intersections

Tags: java, math

I would like to represent a hyperbola in Java (likely as a class), given two foci (A and B) points and a point (C), co-linear to A and B, that lies on the hyperbola.

I already have a Point class:

```
public class Point{
    public int x;
    public int y;

    public Point (int x, int y){
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }
}
```

I also need a way to determine the intersection point(s) of three hyperbolas (they will share three foci points, two each).

I do not need to draw these hyperbolas, just use them to find the intersections.

Alternatively, if there is an easier way to find this intersection point, that would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about math, not programming

Comment: I know the math around it (mostly)... I don't know how to do it in Java.

Comment: Java doesn't have any built-in functions to solve such problems, and any 3rd party libraries are mostly for numerical approximations. My advice is to use the given foci to translate, rotate, and maybe scale the hyperbolas so that it's convenient to find the intersections. At that point you can either work out by hand or maybe use a computer algebra system to find the intersections symbolically (once), and then code that up.